# Ajax cancelando eventos onblur e onfocus

Tags: php, ajax, html5, bootstrap-3

Estou apanhando para chamar um ajax (Bootstrap 3 + Html + PHP), o que acontece é que ao colocar a função $.ajax, simplesmente os eventos não ocorrem, se eu colocar um alert ali os eventos acontecem normalmente :

Alguém já passou por isso ? é alguma incompatibilidade com o Bootstrap, ou é desconhecimento meu mesmo ?

---

```
<script>

    function proximoCampo(atual, proximo){                // salta campo depois de preencher 
        if(atual.value.length >= atual.maxLength){
            document.getElementById(proximo).focus();
        }
    }

    function buscaProduto(){

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "pdv-produto-ajax.php",
            data: {codigoean: '7891111111111'},
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.val);
            }
        });

    }

</script>
```

-------------- HTML -------

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="pdvcodigoean">Código Barras*</label>  
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input id="pdvcodigoean" name="pdvcodigoean" type="text" placeholder="Código Barras EAN13" 
               maxlength="13" class="form-control input-md" required="" autofocus
               pattern=“^*[0-9]”
               onkeyup="proximoCampo(this, 'pdvquantidade')"
               >
    </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="pdvquantidade">Quantidade vendida  </label>  
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input id="pdvquantidade" name="pdvquantidade" type="text" 
               maxlength="13" class="form-control input-md" value="1"
               pattern="[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?" min="0.01" max="9999999.99"
               onfocus="buscaProduto()">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Há algum erro no console? Você também pode checar na ferramenta de desenvolvedor, na aba network (depende do navegador) se a request está retornando ok. Pode estar ocorrendo algum erro e, como você não tem o callback `error` especificado, está passando silenciosamente pelo seu código. Mas, de antemão, dá para perceber que há um erro de sintaxe na formação do objeto data: falta fechar as chaves: `{codigoean: '7891111111111 },`.

Comment: você esqueceu de fechar com `}` após `data:`

Comment: a falta do { foi uma distração no momento de copiar o código, mas mesmo assim o alert não funciona.

Comment: @CarlosSusviela você checou o console se há algum erro? e a requisição na aba da rede foi enviada e retornou os dados esperados?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de tudo, lembre-se da [ordem correta de carregamento das bibliotecas](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template). Se você carrega `bootstrap.min.js` antes de `jquery.min.js`, está errado.

O certo é assim:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Se o carregamento estiver certo, tente:

```
<script>
      $(function(){
       $("#pdvcodigoean").keyup(function() {
         if (this.value.length === this.maxLength) {
          $('#pdvquantidade').focus();
         }
      });
      $("#pdvquantidade").focusin(function() {
       $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "pdv-produto-ajax.php",
         data: {
           codigoean: '7891111111111'
         },
         success: function (data) {
           alert(data.val);
          }
      });                     
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: obrigado pelas dicas, parece ter resolvido mas, estou em um  loop infinito, pois ao mudar o foco para a "pdvquantidade" como a condição de "pdvcodigoean" AINDA é verdadeira  eu acabo retornando para o ajax. 
Vou ter que fazer uma nova pergunta.